# Detecting screen recording settings on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, cocoa, screen-recording, macos-catalina

What's is a reliable way to detect if user has enabled this API?

`CGWindowListCreateImage` returns a valid object even if screen recording API is disabled. There are multiple combinations possible (`kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow`, `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow`) and only some will return NULL.

```
- (CGImageRef)createScreenshotImage
{
    NSWindow *window = [[self view] window];
    NSRect rect = [window frame];

    rect.origin.y = NSHeight([[window screen] frame]) - NSMaxY([window frame]);
    CGImageRef screenshot = CGWindowListCreateImage(
                                                    rect,
                                                    kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow,
                                                    //kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow,
                                                    0,//(CGWindowID)[window windowNumber],
                                                    kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);//kCGWindowImageDefault
    return screenshot;
}
```

The only reliable way is through `CGDisplayStreamCreate` which is risky as Apple always changes privacy settings every year.

```
   - (BOOL)canRecordScreen
    {
        if (@available(macOS 10.15, *)) {
            CGDisplayStreamRef stream = CGDisplayStreamCreate(CGMainDisplayID(), 1, 1, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, nil, ^(CGDisplayStreamFrameStatus status, uint64_t displayTime, IOSurfaceRef frameSurface, CGDisplayStreamUpdateRef updateRef) {
                ;
            });
            BOOL canRecord = stream != NULL;
            if (stream) { 
              CFRelease(stream); 
            }
            return canRecord;
        } else {
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does a user disable the screen recording API?

Comment: Maybe it’s not clear. There is new privacy switch in catalina. Usage of the API will trigger a privacy window where user has 2 options: 1)deny, 2)open system settings and enable manually. There is no allow button.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I can't help with your question but that's good to know :)

Comment: @MarekH Can we bypass/suppress this privacy window.

Comment: Any update to the API in macOS 11 ?

Comment: @Jimmy Yes. Usage of CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess()

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apple provides direct low level api to check for access and grant access. No need to use tricky workarounds.

```
/* Checks whether the current process already has screen capture access */
@available(macOS 10.15, *)
public func CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess() -> Bool
```

Use the above functions to check for screen capture access.

if access is not given use the below function to prompt for access

```
/* Requests event listening access if absent, potentially prompting */
@available(macOS 10.15, *)
public func CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess() -> Bool
```

[Screenshot taken from documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTdwV.png)

Comment: Added in macOS11 beta 3. Just need to verify if it works correctly on all versions of 10.15 http://codeworkshop.net/objc-diff/sdkdiffs/macos/11.0b3/CoreGraphics.html

Comment: Interesting that the community was unaware of this API for so long.

Comment: This seems to work well on Big Sur but crashes in Catalina (at least 10.15.7).

Comment: It crashes only if you fail to call it on the main queue. This works well for me:

`dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess();
});`

Comment: @Jezevec Was naive and just got 300 crash reports all for 10.15 and 0 for 10.16/11.0. This API doesn't exists on 10.15. Will fill radar

Comment: Thanks. Please note that the API cannot be used to detect the change while the app is running. That is, the app has to be restarted after the user has granted the permission in order for the check to success.

Comment: The same behavior (getting "old" status from your launch-time) is observed with other similar APIs (e.g. checks for permission for Accessibility). I opened a bug for this at Apple, and got official approval that this is the behavior in a DTS incident).

Comment: @JordanH: Correct, the API is only available in macOS 11 because of a [bug](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683860?answerId=684400022#684400022).

Answer (score 30):

All of the solutions presented here have a flaw in one way or another. The root of the problem is that there's no correlation between your permission to know about a window (via the name in the window list), your permission to know about the process owner of the window (such as WindowServer and Dock). Your permission to view the pixels on screen is a combination of two sparse sets of information.

Here is a heuristic that covers all the cases as of macOS 10.15.1:

```c
BOOL canRecordScreen = YES;
if (@available(macOS 10.15, *)) {
    canRecordScreen = NO;
    NSRunningApplication *runningApplication = NSRunningApplication.currentApplication;
    NSNumber *ourProcessIdentifier = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:runningApplication.processIdentifier];

    CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
    NSUInteger numberOfWindows = CFArrayGetCount(windowList);
    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfWindows; index++) {
        // get information for each window
        NSDictionary *windowInfo = (NSDictionary *)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowList, index);
        NSString *windowName = windowInfo[(id)kCGWindowName];
        NSNumber *processIdentifier = windowInfo[(id)kCGWindowOwnerPID];

        // don't check windows owned by this process
        if (! [processIdentifier isEqual:ourProcessIdentifier]) {
            // get process information for each window
            pid_t pid = processIdentifier.intValue;
            NSRunningApplication *windowRunningApplication = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:pid];
            if (! windowRunningApplication) {
                // ignore processes we don't have access to, such as WindowServer, which manages the windows named "Menubar" and "Backstop Menubar"
            }
            else {
                NSString *windowExecutableName = windowRunningApplication.executableURL.lastPathComponent;
                if (windowName) {
                    if ([windowExecutableName isEqual:@"Dock"]) {
                        // ignore the Dock, which provides the desktop picture
                    }
                    else {
                        canRecordScreen = YES;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    CFRelease(windowList);
}
```

If `canRecordScreen` is not set, you'll need to put up some kind of dialog that warns the user that they'll only be able to see the menubar, desktop picture, and the app's own windows. Here's [how we presented it](https://blog.iconfactory.com/2019/08/xscope-catalina-and-screen-recording/) in our app [xScope](https://xscopeapp.com).

And yes, I'm still bitter that these protections were introduced with [little regard to usability](https://twitter.com/chockenberry/status/1184189991460585472).

Comment: Works great! Swift 5 version: https://gist.github.com/soffes/da6ea98be4f56bc7b8e75079a5224b37

Comment: Do we know if this works when the device is not set to English? It looks like a good solution but having the word "Dock" there makes me worried... though I guess executable names should be the same..

Comment: @max-chuquimia Yes, it will work when the device is not set to English. Craig's using lastPathComponent, not localizedName, so the name is the true executable file, not the localized name for it. I tested this explicitly when writing similar code for my app (Default Folder X).

Comment: Will this work if there are no open windows? This is obviously an edge-case and there are plenty of other system windows hanging around, but just curios, whether this is a bulletproof solution when an app gets installed on a clean macOS and runs this check. Can there be a situation when there are simply no windows to determine this accurately?

Comment: Thanks so much for this code, I have my doubts I'd have figured it out myself! Having now added this check to some software I maintain, I started getting some crash reports in it. Looks like `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` returns `NULL` sometimes.  I'm not clear on the exact circumstances yet, it should be a fairly unusual situation, but looks like we need to handle it.

Comment: This does not work if there are no windows open on the screen.

Comment: @MaxChuquimia you'll need to go through one more step - identify "Dock" not by name but by its bundle ID which is not language dependent (com.apple.dock), then ask Dock's bundle about its "Localized name" and then look for that in the Window's Name.

Comment: NEW: CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess()->Bool has been added according to documentation. Following answer is accepted as a correct solution in 2021  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423834/2648673

Comment: Unfortunately, despite the API docs, CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess and CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess are not implemented in Catalina and will crash if used in 10.15.

Answer (score 4):

@marek-h posted a good example that can detect the screen recording setting without showing privacy alert.
Btw, @jordan-h mentioned that this solution doesn't work when the app presents an alert via beginSheetModalForWindow.

I found that SystemUIServer process is always creating some windows with names: AppleVolumeExtra, AppleClockExtra, AppleBluetoothExtra ...

We can't get the names of these windows, before the screen recording is enabled in Privacy preferences. And when we can get one of these names at least, then it means that the user has enabled screen recording.

So we can check the names of the windows (created by SystemUIServer process) to detect the screen recording preference, and it works fine on macOS Catalina.

```
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#include <libproc.h>

bool isScreenRecordingEnabled()
{
    if (@available(macos 10.15, *)) {
        bool bRet = false;
        CFArrayRef list = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID);
        if (list) {
            int n = (int)(CFArrayGetCount(list));
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                NSDictionary* info = (NSDictionary*)(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(list, (CFIndex)i));
                NSString* name = info[(id)kCGWindowName];
                NSNumber* pid = info[(id)kCGWindowOwnerPID];
                if (pid != nil && name != nil) {
                    int nPid = [pid intValue];
                    char path[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE+1];
                    int lenPath = proc_pidpath(nPid, path, PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE);
                    if (lenPath > 0) {
                        path[lenPath] = 0;
                        if (strcmp(path, "/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/MacOS/SystemUIServer") == 0) {
                            bRet = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            CFRelease(list);
        }
        return bRet;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also working when the app presents an alert via beginSheetModalForWindow.

Comment: Please add an explanation with your answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi Fred, can you please explain more in detail why this should work. It would be nicer if people see an example. Your  solution doesn't count number of windows on screen. It also can't be used as copy paste cause has some unknown constants like sl_true

Comment: Hi Marek, I updated the post with additional description and example code.

Comment: `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly` was not working for full-screen mode, so I changed it to `kCGWindowListOptionAll` and then it is fine.

Comment: A question: who promised to you SystemUIServer will ALWAYS have these windows? or any windows? I can think of many scenarios where the OS has no onscreen windows. This hack is only good if you can find a window that is promised to exist by some process. Why not use our own window for this task? this way we can ensure its existence, visibility, availability etc.

Comment: I don't understand. We're asking for "Screen Recording Permissions" for a specific App... what do we care about the names of SystemUIServer's windows?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an API that's specifically for getting the screen recording permission status. Besides creating a `CGDisplayStream` and checking for nil, the [Advances in macOS Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/701/) WWDC presentation also mentioned that certain metadata from the `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` API will not be returned unless permission is granted. So something like this does seem to work, although it has the same issue of relying on implementation details of that function:

```
private func canRecordScreen() -> Bool {
    guard let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.optionOnScreenOnly], kCGNullWindowID) as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return false }
    return windows.allSatisfy({ window in
        let windowName = window[kCGWindowName as String] as? String
        return windowName != nil
    })
}
```

Comment: Swift code makes me smile. a bit cryptic for my taste yet so concise! One question though: some windows may not  have a name! - yet you require "allSatisfy", and will return false even if a single window has no name. Isn't this a bug? Maybe it is enough to have obtained just one name, to know you have screen-capture permissions?

Answer (score 1):

As of Nov19 [chockenberry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58985069/2648673) has correct answer.

As @onelittlefish pointed out the `kCGWindowName` is being omitted in case user has not enabled the screen recording access in privacy pane. This method also doesn't trigger the privacy alert.

```
- (BOOL)canRecordScreen
{
    if (@available(macOS 10.15, *)) {
        CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
        NSUInteger numberOfWindows = CFArrayGetCount(windowList);
        NSUInteger numberOfWindowsWithName = 0;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < numberOfWindows; idx++) {
            NSDictionary *windowInfo = (NSDictionary *)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowList, idx);
            NSString *windowName = windowInfo[(id)kCGWindowName];
            if (windowName) {
                numberOfWindowsWithName++;
            } else {
                //no kCGWindowName detected -> not enabled
                break; //breaking early, numberOfWindowsWithName not increased
            }

        }
        CFRelease(windowList);
        return numberOfWindows == numberOfWindowsWithName;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I find this works well until my app presents an alert via `beginSheetModalForWindow`. It goes from detecting 31 out of 31 windows with names to 17 out of 31. Do you know why that is?

Comment: This occurs in the public release as well. If any app has an alert presented this returns NO when screen recording is enabled. :(

Comment: @JordanH You can fallback to CGDisplayStreamCreate which is mentioned in question, it's one of the solution. However, it triggers the alert

Answer (score 1):

As of MacOS 10.15.7 the heuristics of obtaining window-names for visible windows, and so know we have screen-capture permission, doesn't always work. Sometimes we just don't find valid windows we can query, and would wrongly deduce we don't have permissions.

However, I found another way to directly query (using sqlite) the Apple TCC database - the model where permissions are persisted. The screen-recording permissions are to be found in the "System level" TCC database ( residing in `/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db`). If you open the database using sqlite, and query: `SELECT allowed FROM access WHERE client="com.myCompany.myApp" AND service="kTCCServiceScreenCapture"` you'll get your answer.

Two downsides comparing to other answers:

- to open this TCC.db database, your app must have "**Full Disk Access**" permission. It doesn't need to run with 'root' privileges, and root privileges won't help if you don't have the "Full disk access".
- it takes about 15 millisec to run, which is slower than querying the window list.

The up side -- it's a direct query of the actual thing, and does not rely on any windows, or processes to exist at the time of query.

Here's some draft code to do this:

```
NSString *client = @"com.myCompany.myApp";
sqlite3 *tccDb = NULL;
sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;

NSString *pathToSystemTCCDB = @"/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db";
const char *pathToDBFile = [pathToSystemTCCDB fileSystemRepresentation];
if (sqlite3_open(pathToDBFile, &tccDb) != SQLITE_OK)
   return nil;
    
const char *query = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT allowed FROM access WHERE client=\"%@\" AND service=\"kTCCServiceScreenCapture\"",client] UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(tccDb, query , -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK)
   return nil;
    
BOOL allowed = NO;
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    allowed |= (sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0) == 1);

if (statement)
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

if (tccDb)
    sqlite3_close(tccDb);

return @(allowed);
```

}

Comment: kTCCServiceScreenCapture is not there anymore in the access tables. in the macOS monterey. Do you know how to get around that?

Comment: I'll just need to open the tables, and look for the new name of the attribute... I guess you could do the same. Any SQLite viewer would do. This is not documented anywhere of course - and I would add a third "downside" that Apple may change this anytime, while APIs are surviving longer.

Answer (score 0):

The most favorable answer is not exactly right, he left out some sences, like sharing state.

we can find the answer in WWDC(https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/701/?time=1007)

Here are some excerpts from WWDC:
the window name and sharing state are not available, unless the user has preapproved the app for screen recording. And this is because some apps put sensitive data such as account names or more likely web page URLs in the window's name.

```
- (BOOL)ScreeningRecordPermissionCheck {
    if (@available(macOS 10.15, *)) {
        CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
        NSUInteger numberOfWindows = CFArrayGetCount(windowList);
        NSUInteger numberOfWindowsWithInfoGet = 0;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < numberOfWindows; idx++) {

            NSDictionary *windowInfo = (NSDictionary *)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowList, idx);
            NSString *windowName = windowInfo[(id)kCGWindowName];
            NSNumber* sharingType = windowInfo[(id)kCGWindowSharingState];

            if (windowName || kCGWindowSharingNone != sharingType.intValue) {
                numberOfWindowsWithInfoGet++;
            } else {
                NSNumber* pid = windowInfo[(id)kCGWindowOwnerPID];
                NSString* appName = windowInfo[(id)kCGWindowOwnerName];
                NSLog(@"windowInfo get Fail pid:%lu appName:%@", pid.integerValue, appName);
            }
        }
        CFRelease(windowList);
        if (numberOfWindows == numberOfWindowsWithInfoGet) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What about windows that don't have a name, and aren't "shared" ?

Comment: It may be working on Catalina but not working in Monterey

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is not working fine. Below is the correct answer.

```
private var canRecordScreen : Bool {
    guard let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.optionOnScreenOnly], kCGNullWindowID) as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return false }
    return windows.allSatisfy({ window in
        let windowName = window[kCGWindowName as String] as? String
        let isSharingEnabled = window[kCGWindowSharingState as String] as? Int
        return windowName != nil || isSharingEnabled == 1
    })
  }
```

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: How can the API Permission for Screen Recording be granted. In the System Preferences I see no "+" to add an App, to grant "screen recording"

Comment: This worked for me. The answer above was very hard to pass into Swift because of the unsafe pointers. This worked.