# How to check permission status of screen capture in electron (macOS catalina)

Tags: reactjs, macos, electron, macos-catalina

I am working on electron app.In the app, there is feature of screen recording and send that to server.We can check a microphone permission status using getMediaAccessStatus api but how can we check a screen recording permission status?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58985069/233944

Comment: @TheNextman: I need for electronjs

Comment: How are you able to ask for permission for screen recording I don't see any functions to open the permissions dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is npm plugin which provide the apis to Check and request permission to capture the screen on macOS (introduced with 10.15 Catalina)

[mac-screen-capture-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mac-screen-capture-permissions)

Comment: mac-screen-capture-permissions is not working in 10.15 Catalina

Comment: @MitalJoshi can you show your code here..... because its working for me

Comment: Have a look in following Code :
------------------
if (process.platform == "darwin") {const {hasScreenCapturePermission,hasPromptedForPermission} = require('mac-screen-capture-permissions');}
function checkPermission(callback) {
    if (process.platform == "darwin" && macVersion.version.includes('10.15') {
            if (hasScreenCapturePermission()) {
                callback();
            } else {
              alert('Screen Capture permission is mandatory for Clock In. Please provide it from System Prefrence.');
            }
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

Comment: @MitalJoshi

You can use this way to get permission state value.



      const types = ["camera", "microphone", "screen"];

      let accessPerms = {};

      for (const type of types) {
        const status = systemPreferences.getMediaAccessStatus(type);
        accessPerms[type] = status;
      }

accessPerms will store all your permission state.
Note use latest electron version.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this one but I am Getting 'granted' every time, Even if it is not granted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new solution

```html
 if (process.platform === "darwin") {
    try {
      // prompt for permissions on macOS
      const types = ["camera", "microphone", "screen"];
      let accessPerms = {};

      for (const type of types) {
        const status = systemPreferences.getMediaAccessStatus(type);
        accessPerms[type] = status;
      }
     } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If permission for screen recording is not present how can i ask for permission and open system preferences window