# CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess always returns false in development builds

Tags: swift, cocoa, screen-recording, macos-monterey

I'm writing an app for macOS (12.1 locally) in Xcode 13.2.1. I need screenshot access, and it seems like the easiest way to get permission for that (in macOS 11 and later) is to use `CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess`, and to check eligibility using `CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423834/444912

My code essentially looks like this:

```swift
let hasScreenAccess = CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess();
if (!hasScreenAccess) {
    CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess()
}
```

When I run a fresh build, a modal appears as expected:
[image: Screenshot of app requresting recording permissions]

and I'm able to see my app appear in System Preferences, also as expected:
[image: Screenshot of app in Screen Recording permissions section of System Preferences]

Enabling my app's permissions prompts me to quit my app and restart it. This restarts my *production* copy of my app, from the app store. However, if I quit that and re-run the same build in XCode, my build is still not granted permission to record the screen (even though it appears as enabled in System Preferences). How do I allow my app to have permissions to record my screen locally?

Answer (score 5):

We had a similar issue after renaming one of our apps which made use of the `/usr/sbin/screencapture` command line tool. The security prompt appeared every time a screen capture was triggered, no matter the activation status in System Preferences.

During development, the `tccutil reset ScreenCapture {bundle identifier}` command helped keep the permissions clean for subsequent testing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in the process of writing this question, so I figured I'd share my answer. If I delete the copy of my app from my Applications folder, things seem to work. I assume that there is some sort of "claiming" process that goes.

It seems to work if I rename the copy of the app in my Applications folder, delete the screen recording in System Preferences, and then run my fresh build from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences, it can be *the production copy of your app*. You may need to replace it with your debug build app.

1. Delete it from System Preferences.
2. Locate your debug build app in Finder and drag & drop it to System Preferences.

Your debug build app must be given the permission.